# Case-insensitive primary key in Oracle

Tags: oracle

The semantic of our data is case insensitive, so we configure the oracle sessions to be case insensitive:

```
alter session set NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI;
```

Then, to take advantage of indexes we would also want the primary key to be case insensitive as well:

```
create table SCHEMA_PROPERTY (
  NAME  nvarchar2(64)   not null,
  VALUE nvarchar2(1024),
  constraint SP_PK primary key (nlssort(NAME))
)
```

However, this runs into "ORA-00904: : invalid identifier", so I assume it is not possible to use the nlssort() function in the PK definition.

Next attempt was to associate a case-insensitive unique index to the primary key:

```
create table SCHEMA_PROPERTY (
  NAME  nvarchar2(64) primary key using index (
      create unique index SP_UQ on SCHEMA_PROPERTY(nlssort(NAME))),
  VALUE nvarchar2(1024)
);
```

but this failed too:

```
Error: ORA-14196: Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint.
14196. 00000 -  "Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint."
*Cause:    The index specified to enforce the constraint is unsuitable
           for the purpose.
*Action:   Specify a suitable index or allow one to be built automatically.
```

Should I just conclude that Oracle does not support case-insensitive semantics for a PK constraint? This works fine in MSSQL which has a simpler approach in dealing with collations.

We could, of course, create a unique index instead of the primary key, but I wanted to make sure first that the normal way to do this is not supported.

Our oracle version is 11.2.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are on 11.2 you can use a virtual column to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA_PROPERTY (
   REAL_NAME  nvarchar2(64) not null,
   NAME       generated always as (lower(real_name)) primary key,
   VALUE nvarchar2(1024)
);
```

Comment: There's no difference between lower() and nlssort(). The point of my post it that it doesn't seem possible to define a PK based on a function. The PK can only be based on an actual column.

Comment: @BogdanCalmac: you are right, sorry should have tested that before posting. With 11.x there is a workaround, see my edit

Comment: We have to support Oracle 10g also, but even without that it looks uglier than using a unique index instead of a primary key.

Comment: @BogdanCalmac: if you can use a unique index, then yes by all means use it! I thought you needed the PK definition in order to create a foreign key to that table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index to enforce case-insensitive PK:

```
create table SCHEMA_PROPERTY (
  NAME  nvarchar2(64),
  VALUE nvarchar2(1024),
  constraint SP_PK primary key (NAME)
);

create unique index SP_UN on SCHEMA_PROPERTY(lower(NAME));
```